# Ambiguity from the placement of a prepositional phrase

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

Consider:

> The executive director presented to the board her final recommendations on fundraising and the dissemination of those funds.

This does not read well and moving *to the board* would be a natural thing to do,

> The executive director presented her final recommendations on fundraising **to the board**.

if it wasn't for the last part:

> The executive director presented her final recommendations on fundraising **and the dissemination of those funds** to the board.

This, I presume, would introduce an ambiguity (are the funds disseminated to the board?)

Is there a solution?

[Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikipedia_Signpost/2012-03-12/News_and_notes) (near "Final Gardner recommendations published").

Comment: It's largely a matter of style how you phrase this. There would be no ambiguity in your third version when **spoken** - and as J.R. points out, you'd trivially indicate this using commas if you really thought it might be misunderstood. Though frankly I think it would be a perverse interpretation anyway, to suppose any such board would be sharing the fundraising proceeds amongst themselves.

Comment: So is it really the ambiguity in the NP of what is presented? That is, 'her final recommendations on fundraising and the dissemination of those funds to the board.' the meaning could be that the recommendations are to the board vs. the dissemination is to the board. Is that where the ambiguity is?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Perhaps that's a "perverse" interpretation in this context, but that doesn't make the general question any less valid.  Consider this sentence, which has the same structure: _The executive director presented her recommendations on constitutional changes and the mailing of election ballots to the board_.  Now, it's not so obvious - was the director talking to the board about mailing ballots to everyone in the company?  Or talking about how ballots would be mailed to everyone on the board?

Comment: @J.R.: In the more general sense, vast numbers of constructions (particularly in writing, not speech) are technically "ambiguous". Your commas easily (but imho, unnecessarily) resolved OP's one. Sometimes the only way around it is to rephrase. *This particular instance* isn't really much of a model for resolving ambiguity in general, but I stand by my first comment that it's a matter of style how OP phrases it, and if he's bothered about the ambiguity - well, just learn to use commas appropriately.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to simply answer a question than pick it apart.  In this case, it matters not how the sentence would sound when _spoken_; presumably, the OP was asking about the sentence when _written_.  (Otherwise, he could have said, "This does not sound right," instead of, "This does not read well," and not bothered to provide a link to a news article where the sentence was taken verbatim.)

Comment: @J.R.: Well, I upvoted your answer (although I *don't* like "before" here), and I didn't downvote or vote to close the question, but in the end this looks like a "how can I phrase this better" type of question that probably should be on writers.se anyway. I don't see anything useful about English usage emerging from it - just a slew of alternative phrasings that wouldn't even be needed in **real** (spoken) English.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the preposition *to* with *before*, which means "in front of" according to [Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/before?q=before). The sentence will be:

> The executive director presented her final recommendations on fundraising and the dissemination of those funds before the board.

There is no ambiguity with this change.

Answer (score 4):

I like Irene's suggestion, using the word *before*.

In a similar situation, where a preposition change would be less suitable, you could also use punctuation:

> The executive director presented her final recommendations on fundraising, and on the dissemination of those funds, to the board.

Answer (score 3):

In UK English, *before* would seldom be used in this way. I would prefer the use of the preposition *with*:

> The executive director presented the board with her final recommendations on fundraising and the dissemination of those funds.

Comment: When you *present someone with something* you usually *give* it to them, you don't just show them.

Comment: I don't see a distinction; her recommendations are given.

Comment: You might be right. But I've seen (and heard) **present** with this constuct only when a gift is offered to someone in a formal situation.

Comment: I don't know if this is a UK difference that we are addressing, Irene. The construct is common in UK although I would agree that it tends towards the formal (as a board situation might be viewed).

Comment: I agree it is a common UK construct (I can't speak about American English, I know only what I hear in films and read in books). So far I'd connected *present someone with something* with award or gift offering in formal situations, but then again my experience might be more limited than yours.

Answer (score 0):

> To the board, the executive director presented her final
>   recommendations on fundraising and the dissemination of those funds.

Answer (score 0):

In a presentation before the board, the executive director detailed her final recommendations on fundraising and the dissemination of those funds.