# Confusing use of 'to' preposition

Tags: prepositions

Recently I came across a technical article. It had following section heading:

> Forwarding references to DOM components

If we see the statement in isolation, without surrounding text, which of the following meaning of the statement is correct?

1. references are being forwarded to DOM components
2. references to DOM components are being forwarded

How can I rephrase the statement to clearly convey meaning no. 1?
How can I rephrase the statement to clearly convey meaning no. 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ambiguity from the placement of a prepositional phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61462/ambiguity-from-the-placement-of-a-prepositional-phrase) ('The executive director presented her final recommendations on fundraising and the dissemination of those funds to the board.')

Answer (score 1):

Either meaning 1. or 2. can apply to the statement. The two meanings that you provided are sufficient to rephrase the statement. Meaning 2. can be made more clear as follows:

2. DOM component references are being forwarded

Comment: I think the meaning 2 can be made more concise: "Forwarding DOM component references"

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to make the meaning clear without using a finite verb. (Your original doesn't have a finite verb, as is normal for a section heading.) Here are some possibilities:

> References to DOM components: forwarding

> References: forwarding to DOM components

Note that the original text contains another ambiguity: Is someone forwarding the references (i.e., "references" functions as the direct object of "forwarding"), or are the references themselves doing the forwarding (i.e., "forwarding" modifies "references")? My suggestions assume the former.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think of the third case. 